# How to detect all keys in JSON passed as null or not passed

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I had a task checking if input JSON contains all obligatory keys (for copying parsed keys - values into the table with not null attributes e.i.) and raising an error if it does not. I used to use num_nulls something like:

```
if select num_nulls(jsn->>'key a', jsn->>'key b', jsn->>'key c', jsn->>'key d') > 0 then
    return false;
end if;
```

Then I got a task to determine which exactly key weren't passed and I made a piece of code:

```
declare
    f_json    jsonb;
    obl_arr   text[];
    ret_string text;
begin
    obl_arr = array['key a', 'key b', 'key c', 'key d'];
    f_json = jsonb_strip_nulls(inp_json::jsonb); -- inp_json - input parameter in the function as a text or json(b)

    ret_string = (select string_agg(x.key, ',' order by key)
                  from (select unnest(obl_arr) as key
                        except
                        select *
                        from jsonb_object_keys(f_json)) x);
    return ret_string;
```

I will be grateful if you advise me on another more straightforward way to return empty keys.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE

> jsonb ?& text[] → boolean
> Do all of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or
> array elements?
>
> '["a", "b", "c"]'::jsonb ?& array['a', 'b'] → t

So you can use

```
select jsn ?& array['key a', 'key b', key c];
```

> determine which exactly key weren't passed

You code is just fine. jsonb extract the keys, then compare with your input strings.

Comment: Thank you much
select jsn ?& array['key a', 'key b', 'key c'];  returns boolean but I need a list of keys - diff between the left side and right side.
If I would be able to subtract one array from another it would be great but I didn't find any operator neither for array nor for JSON
Or maybe I didn't understand you well

Comment: @OlehSydor I solved your first tasks. But  I said you code is fine to solve the second task. If you code not working, then You can use dbfiddl.uk share you sample code.

Comment: Ah, sorry
Yes, your code for the first task is more convenient.
Thanks again